# Jquery dynamic loading link changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `dynamicpage.js` script below:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;
    
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };
    
});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

What that code does is it makes a link turn from `href="/staff"` to `href="/#/staff"` for the dynamic loading but it only changes the link if the `<a>` tag is wrapped in a `<nav>` tag so
it only works if its `<nav><a href="/staff">staff</a></nav>`

I tried to make it ("#dynamic") in the jquery/js and added id="dynamic" to the `<a>` tag but it did not work.

How would I make it so I can just add id="dynamic" to the `<a>` tag instead of wrapping `<nav>` around EACH link i want to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use event delegation instead ..

It can be attached to the document to be triggered wherever the link is located in the DOM ( and because click event is not a flooding one like mosemove)

Then simply add the 'dynamic' class to those links concerned by this behaviour

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    var $t = $(e.target),
        $a = $t.closest('a.dynamic');

    if( $a.length ){
        window.location.hash = $a.attr('href');
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: It provokes a nervous twitch :-) to add a listener for something as fundamental as 'click' on something as high up as 'document' but it could well be better than iterating over a bazillion links! If the number of clicks on non-link things is expected to be small, then even if 't.closest' runs slowly, it should be OK. If there's a lot of interactivity expected for non-link elements, it'd be time to do some profiling and see which approach was best (essentially it's a run-time overhead after page load for your solution, versus a load-time overhead for per-link listeners).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, though I'm not sure I do...

Just adding in an ID to a link won't do what you want, because an ID by itself doesn't mean anything to a web browser. It's the web browser that's responsible for doing Stuff when a user follows a link, which by default would be to follow that link and load a page; you're modifying the link address so that the interesting stuff is actually held in a named anchor (hence the "#") then relying on a JavaScript event listener to catch the "click" event and do something novel.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1

There's no way around the need to attach this listener to every link that needs the special treatment.

By making sure you generate HTML such that the "interesting" links have a specific common named class though, you can at least use the jQuery equivalent of `document.getElementsByClassName`, which ought to be simpler and faster than using a CSS selector based approach as in your example code.

- http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

You will still have to iterate over this and add listeners. Is it *really* worth all this JavaScript, CPU overhead and browser incompatibility risks (especially on mobile) just to override the behaviour of a link that browsers already deal with pretty adequately? All that history patching you have to do as well (whether or not it's hidden by a framework)? Just to avoid a page refresh? Personally, I'm really not sure it is!